# Powershell : How to Remove Duplicates

Tags: powershell

Made changes to code after trying suggested methods

### The query picks data from Mysql tables which is updated every two minutes. Query is stored in a .csv file for use in latter part of dev. I need to pick data which wasn’t present in the previous loop ,i.e. compare dataset tables over a column data, so that repeating data can be excluded.

```
The source code is :
foreach($line in $csv)
{
$MySQLQuery=$line.query
$mycommand = New-Object 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($MySQLQuery,$myConnection)
$dataAdapter = New-Object 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($mycommand)
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet,"data")                                          
$mycommand.Dispose()
$newData  = $dataSet.Tables["data"] 
$rowCount = $newData.Rows.count 

if($rowCount -ne 0)
{
if($previousData -eq $null ){$extractedData =  $newData;} 
else {$extractedData = Compare-object  $previousData $newData | Where { 
$_.SideIndicator -like "=>" } | Select -ExpandProperty InputObject } 
$previousData = $newData 
 }
```

> The `$newData` contains tables with column name *"stock_name"* based
>   on which the duplicates have to be removed. $previousData is of type
>   datatable and is used to store the data from previous iteration .
>   $extractedData is to hold the difference data .

========================================================================

Comment: What output you are getting? And what is `$previousdata` type?

Comment: harsh-jaswal :find above the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that you want that data in `$extractedData` which is new in `$newDataset` as compared to `$previousData` on the basis of `stock_name`.
So for that you can change your `Compare-object` like this:

```
if($newDataset.Rows.count -gt $previousData.Rows.count){
$extractedData = $newDataset | ? { ($previousData.stock_name -notcontains $_.stock_name)
}
else
{ $extractedData = $newDataset}
```

It will work I guess.

Comment: yes , it works when newDataset > previousData, but can i include a code in the same line to send the newDataset  , if newDataset < previousData ?

Comment: Its not about `>` or `<`. Generally what it does, it will return only those records which are not in the `$previousData`

Comment: So it wont make any difference if it is > or <

Comment: yes , i agree harsh . i want to change the code such that if in the newDataset , records are lesser than previousData ; send newdataset completely

Comment: Then you can use one `if` condition like:
if(new>prev){"put that line here"} else{excract = new}

Comment: that worked , modified code to if($previousData -eq $null ){$extractedData =  $newData;} 
else {
 $extractedData = $newData | ? { ($previousData.stock_name -notcontains $_.stock_name)}
if(($extractedData -eq $null) -and ($newData.Rows.count -lt $previousData.Rows.count) )
{
$extractedData = $newData
}

Comment: This was not your requirement when you asked the question. I told you the main logic how you can remove the duplicate records from the DataSet. Others if-else logic you can apply according to your requirement.

Comment: If your problem is solved with this logic then please mark it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the new data, why are you looking like you want the previous data? Try filtering and expanding the results of the `Compare-Object` cmdlet. The code below returns only the ";lkj" data.

```
$DatasetTable = "asdf","qwer","zxcv"

$newData = "asdf","qwer","zxcv",";lkj"

$newDataSet = Compare-object $DatasetTable $newData | Where { $_.SideIndicator -like "=>" } | Select -ExpandProperty InputObject

$newDataSet
```

It's hard to say though because I don't see where your `$previousdata` variable is established prior to your first `+=` operator.

Comment: :this seems to fail over a number of iterations . tried the below code :                      $properties = ($previousData | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
foreach ($property in $properties) {
$extractedData =  Compare-Object $previousData $newData -Property "$property" | Format-Table -AutoSize ;again fails to return the difference data

Comment: Glad to see you got your answer though!